# Tridion Community Ideas on SDL Community

Tags: discussion

I added two questions (about BluePrinting metaphors and info for upgrades) in a new ideas and challenges section of the SDL Community Tridion Developer's group.

**Check them out on [SDL Community](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/i).**